# Storing images in MySql using python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, image, path

I have used a function named InsertBlob to insert images in Mysql by letting users input the file path but the error i often get is " it must be of type list, tuple or dict"..is there a way to overcome the error or must i do one whole different coding to get what i want?

```
def InsertBlob(FilePath):
    with open(FilePath, "rb") as File:
        BinaryData = File.read()

    SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO Images (Photo) VALUES (%s)".format(BinaryData)
    print(SQLStatement)
    MyCursor.execute(SQLStatement , BinaryData)
    
    print("1.Insert Image\n2. Read Image")
    MenuInput = input()
    if int(MenuInput) == 1:
      UserFilePath = input("Enter File Path: ")
      InsertBlob(UserFilePath)
```

Comment: Hi Yogendran, please input an error log so we can isolate root cause of problem. `the error i often get is " it must be of type list, tuple or dict"..` unfortunately is very little to work with.

Comment: Storing images in MySQL is not general practice, you should prefer to store images on the directories instead of the Database. You should store the image directory path on the database, and store the image in the directory, not the database.  Generally, image sizes are larger than an MB and cause the put load on the database.